# MEMORY OPTIMIZED Tables - Why not use it for all tables?

Tags: sql-server

I am learning about MEMORY OPTIMIZED tables and MEMORY OPTIMIZED table types now and it seems to be a wonderful feature of SQL Server 2016 in terms of performance.

After investigation, I still do not understand why not using this feature for all the tables and how SQL Server will manage situations of "out of memory" for MEMORY OPTIMIZED tables data.

Will be interesting to learn, in what scenarios I should consider using it and when it's not recommended.

Comment: You wouldn't use it for all tables as it would be used to improve performance, and querying certain tables wouldn't be a performance issue. You would use it only on suitable candidate tables that would help improve performance issues. For example, you may have a query to identify a users role when they log in, that wouldn't need to be optimised. You may have a log table with millions of rows, that is simply an audit table that has no exposure to users, that wouldn't need to be optimised. Identifying bottlenecks and testing will highlight candidates for memory optimized tables.

Comment: >>>why not using this feature for all the tables<<< How big are your databases? Have you any database of 10Tb? Do you have 10Tb of RAM on your server and do you want to wait when at every restart all the 10Tb will be read from disk into memory?

Comment: Because you really only see the performance increase if the stored procedures that operate on them are also memory optimised, and there area lot of limitations in what you can include in these stored procedures. So the next best thing is just have as much RAM as your database so it's always cached